# Swift Alamofire response status code

Tags: swift, alamofire

How can I get status code from the Alamofire `response`?

In the latest version I can use `validate` but I need to check what the status code is.

Code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/url")
         .responseJSON { response in

         }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33192390/3405387

Comment: Try `response.response.statusCode`.

Comment: This works, it looks bad, but its working :)

Answer (score 5):

This works (after @MirzaDelic pointed out my mistake):

```
Alamofire.request(.get, "http://www.google.com")
    .responseJSON { response in
        if response.response.statusCode == 404 {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but this works: `response.response.statusCode`

Comment: Ah ok.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In Alamofire 4.0 swift3 branch, I needed exactly:

```
Alamofire.request(request, withMethod: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: .url, headers: nil)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                print("...HTTP code: \(statusCode)")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While the above methods will work, there is a more efficient way to do this. `response.response.statusCode` returns a status code that could very in large amounts. Alamofire includes two functions that are useful for this case, `isSuccess` and `isFailure`.

```
Alamofire.request(.get, "http://example.com/url").responseJSON { response in
    let responseErrorCode = response.response!.statusCode

    if response.result.isSuccess {
         print("Successful HTTP code: \(responseErrorCode)")

         // Run code if request is successful

    } else if response.result.isFailure {
         print("Failure HTTP code: \(responseErrorCode)")

         // Run code if request isn't successful

    }
}
```

By using the code above you can easily know whether the HTTP code is good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

With Alamofire 5.6, if you add `.validate(statusCode: [200])` to your `AF` request you can then inspect the `AFError` of the result.

```swift
func request(_ requestConvertible: any URLRequestConvertible) async throws {
    switch await AF
        .request(requestConvertible, interceptor: interceptor)
        .validate(statusCode: [200])
        .serializingDecodable(Empty.self, emptyResponseCodes: [200])
        .result {
    case .failure(let error):
        if error.responseCode == 401 {
            // Handle 401 statusCode
        }
        throw error
    case .success:
        break
    }
}
```

Or for a Decodable type (from a JSON response):

```swift
func requestDecodable<Value: Decodable>(_ requestConvertible: any URLRequestConvertible, to type: Value.Type) async throws -> Value {
    let request = AF.request(requestConvertible, interceptor: interceptor)
        .validate(statusCode: [200])
    let response = request.serializingData(emptyResponseCodes: [200])
    let result = await response.result
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        if request.response?.statusCode == 401 {
            // Handle 401 statusCode
        }
        throw error
    case .success(let data):
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
    }
}
```