# Use Json data from network call in UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use the data from my network call to display in the UItableview as cell names

Here is my current view controller

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON




class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    var articles = [Article]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //get data from network call
        loaddata()

        //end view did load
    }

    func loaddata(){

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://ip-address/test.json")
            .responseJSON { response in
                // print(response.request)  // original URL request
                // print(response.response) // URL response
                //print(response.data)     // server data
                //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                /*if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }*/

                //get json from response data
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                //print(json)

                //for loop over json and write all article titles articles array
                for (key, subJson) in json["Articles"] {
                    if let author = subJson["title"].string {
                        let artTitle = Article(name: author)
                        self.articles.append(artTitle!)


                    }
                    /*if let content = subJson["content"].string {
                    // self.Content.append(content)

                    }*/

                }
                // print("\(self.titles)")
                //print("\(self.Content[0])")
                //print(self.articles)

                //set variable to articles number 6 to check append worked
                let name = self.articles[6].name

                //print varibale name to check
                print("\(name)")

        }

        }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        //let num = articles.count
       // print(num)
        //return number of rows
        return articles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        //let (artTitle) = articles[indexPath.row]

        // Fetches the appropriate article for the data source layout.
        let article = articles[indexPath.row]

        //set cell text label to article name
        cell.textLabel?.text = article.name
        return cell
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    //end of class
    }
```

Here is the Article.swift file

```
class Article {
    // MARK: Properties

    var name: String


    // MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name


        // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

I think I am almost there, here is what I can do so far

1. The network call with alamofire is working
2. I can get the article title using swiftJson
3. I then append the article title
4. I can then print from articles after the for loop so I know its working.

I just can't set it to the cell name

Is this because the UItableview is loaded before the data is loaded and hence article will be empty at that point?

Can you point me towards best practice for something such as this/ best design patterns and help me load data in

Comment: Everything looks fine except but in your .request, you need to dispatch to main thread before you update the array since the request is done Asynchronously(in a different thread) and the closure is executed sometime in the future. I gave an answer for similar question not long ago, you can check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33192390/3405387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the data from the request, call reloadData on your tableView on the main thread like so.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    [unowned self] in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

This will make the tableView refresh all of its contents, and your data should show up then.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, Urls.menu).responseJSON { response in
    if let jsonData = response.data {    
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
            let json = JSON(data: jsonData)

            //for loop over json and write all article titles articles array

            newArticles = [Articles]()
            for (key, subJson) in json["Articles"] {
                if let author = subJson["title"].string {
                    if let artTitle = Article(name: author) {
                        newArticles.append(artTitle)
                    }                    
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.articles += newArticles 
                tableView.reloadData()
                /*if let content = subJson["content"].string {
                // self.Content.append(content)

                }*/
            }

            // print("\(self.titles)")
            //print("\(self.Content[0])")
            //print(self.articles)

            //set variable to articles number 6 to check append worked
            let name = self.articles[6].name

            //print varibale name to check
            print("\(name)")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, the answer above helped me with a quick resolution but will certainly look into this for the long run